# Flash builder 4.6 into Eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder, eclipse-indigo

I have flash builder 4.6 and eclipse indigo installed seperately on my window pc.I want to run java code in either flash builder or run flex code in eclipse indigo.Could i use flash builder files to include in eclipse as plugins or use eclipse file in flash builder to fulfill my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either works.  Flash Builder 4.6 is built on Eclipse Indigo 32-bit, and there's a utility to install the FB plug-in to an existing Eclipse 32-bit installation (in the Flash Builder's utities directory, Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 Plug-in Utility.exe).  So, either add the Java plugins to FB, or run the util to plug into Eclipse.  Myself, I ran the utility to plug into an existing Eclipse J2EE installation.